# Installation Error Message Re: Samba4

Tags: software-installation, package-management, samba, xubuntu

Whenever I install software or get a software update, I'm always getting a Samba4 error. Here's a capture:

> Errors were encountered while processing:  samba4 Error in function: 
>   Setting up samba4 (4.0.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ... ERROR(): uncaught exception - unable to parse dn
>   string   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/**init**.py", line 175,
>   in _run
>       return self.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/dbcheck.py", line 108,
>   in run
>       fix=fix, yes=yes, quiet=quiet, in_transaction=started_transaction)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/dbchecker.py", line 56,
>   in **init**
>       self.infrastructure_dn = ldb.Dn(samdb, "CN=Infrastructure," + samdb.domain_dn()) dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure): 
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>   status 255

This particular error occurred after installing Cheese Webcam Booth in Xubuntu 13.04 using the Ubuntu Software Center. I grabbed these details after the installer told me a package operation failed. Cheese seems to have installed just fine. So, this is a nuisance error more than anything else. I'm not even sure Samba4 is misbehaving, as I can print to a shared Windows printer.

Ideas on how to eliminate the messages? Should I uninstall and purge Samba4 and then reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want just the package `samba` instead of `samba4`. I found these 2 threads which seem to be saying that.

- [package samba4 4.0.0~alpha18.dfsg1-4ubuntu2 failed to install/upgrade: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba4/+bug/992820)
- [setoption.pl is not executable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba4/+bug/988509)

Don't let the second links title fool you, it's dealing with the same type of error message as yours.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Newbie here, sorry. How should I proceed? Uninstall and purge Samba4 and then install Samba?

Comment: @AdrianKeister - yes that's what I would do. Don't install `samba4`, install `samba`.

Comment: Great! I'll give that a try and let you know how it works out.

Comment: @AdrianKeister - Awesome, glad that resolved your problem!